# Extract values under a particular section occurring multiple times in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is always helpful here at stackoverflow and need another help yet again.

In this file.txt, I have "Page Statistics section". This section appears 2 times in the file.
I have to extract the values under "DelAck" for SSD and FC. NOTE: These values are for Node 0 and Node 1

I would like to extract the values and put it in  a list for Node 0 and Node 1.
Somewhat like this below:

```
Result:

SSD_0 = [115200, 115200]  // DelAck values for Node 0
SSD_1 = [115200, 115200]  // DelAck values for Node 1
FC_0 = [0, 0]    // DelAck values for Node 0
FC_1 = [0, 0]    // DelAck values for Node 1
```

Here is the file.txt which has the data to be extracted. Page Statistics sections appears multiple time. I have it here for 2 times. Need to extact values for SSD and FC like I mentioned earlier for Node 0 and Node 1 separately as shown above.
Hope I have explained my situation in detail.

```
***************************
file.txt

22:26:35 04/29/2021 ----- Current ----- ---------- Total ----------
    Node Type       Accesses  Hits Hit% Accesses  Hits Hit% LockBlk
       0 Read          75630 39845   53   149728 79438   53       0
       0 Write         47418 19709   42    93184 38230   41       0
       1 Read          74076 38698   52   145810 75445   52       0
       1 Write         42525 16099   38    84975 31751   37       0


        Page Statistics
     --CfcDirty-- ----CfcMax----- -DelAck--
Node  FC NL   SSD    FC NL    SSD FC NL SSD
   0 250  0 14843 19200  0 115200  0  0   0
   1 284  0 15618 19200  0 115200  0  0   0
Press the enter key to stop...


22:26:33 04/29/2021 ----- Current ----- ---------- Total ----------
    Node Type       Accesses  Hits Hit% Accesses  Hits Hit% LockBlk
       0 Read          74098 39593   53    74098 39593   53       0
       0 Write         45766 18521   40    45766 18521   40       0
       1 Read          71734 36747   51    71734 36747   51       0
       1 Write         42450 15652   37    42450 15652   37       0


        Page Statistics
     --CfcDirty-- ----CfcMax----- -DelAck--
Node  FC NL   SSD    FC NL    SSD FC NL SSD
   0 258  0 13846 19200  0 115200  0  0   0
   1 141  0 13356 19200  0 115200  0  0   0
Press the enter key to stop...

***************************
```

Then I would work on getting the average of the values in the list and print to user.

The challenging part is extracting the data under PAGE Statistics for SSD and FC drives.

Any help would be of immense help.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific problem you are trying to solve or understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the format of this file is quite unique, you will have to parse it by hand. You can do this with a simple program such as this:

```
## Function to get the values from these blank-spaced tables
def values(line):
    while '  ' in line:
        line = line.replace('  ',' ')
    line = line[:-1]
    if line[0]==' ':line = line[1:]
    if line[-1]==' ':line = line[:-1]
    return line.split(' ')

## Load the file
inf = open("file.txt","r")
lines = inf.readlines()
inf.close()

## Get the relevant tables
tables = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if 'Page Statistics' in lines[i]:
        tables.append(lines[i+2:i+5])

## Initiate the results dictionary
result = {"Node 0":{}, "Node 1":{}}
for c in ['CfcDirty','CfcMax','DelAck']:
    for n in result.keys():
        result[n][c]={}
        for value in ['FC','NL','SSD']:
            result[n][c][value]=[]

## Parse the tables and fill up the results
for t in tables:
    vnames = values(t[0])
    node0 = values(t[1])
    node1 = values(t[2])
    i = 0
    for c in ['CfcDirty','CfcMax','DelAck']:
        for _ in range(3):
            i+=1
            result['Node 0'][c][vnames[i]].append(node0[i])
            result['Node 1'][c][vnames[i]].append(node1[i])
```

The result will be a dictionary with node, column1, and column2 as keys. So, you can easily get any value from these tables:

```
>> print(result['Node 0']['DelAck']['SSD'])
['0', '0']

>> print(result['Node 1']['CfcMax']['SSD'])
['115200', '115200']
```

Now, you can compose any number of new variables that contain some values from these tables.

(BTW, I don't understand how you get the values for your example: `SSD_0 = [115200, 115200]  // DelAck values for Node 0`. Node 0 always has the value of 0 for SSD in DelAck.)